Did Cain really exist?
Since some biblical characters, like Kings David and Solomon did exist, but others didn't ( I am assuming that Noah didn't,for instance, although some people think he really lived a lot of years ago)
I was wondering ... Did Cain really exist ?? Is he really buried in Kabul ??
The story goes like this : Cain travelled to the actual Iran, and somehow he found redemption for his great sin. Nowadays he is buried in a cemetery in Kabul beneath a mosque of Muslim religion.
https://www.mitele.es/programas-tv/cuarto-milenio/temporada-19/top-videos/tumba-cain-kabul-40_012353011/player/


Why do you think that Noah didn't exist? 2. And is there any particular reason to suppose that Cain didn't exist?
The answer to (2) at least is important information that you should include with this question.


There are not historical evidences of those things ... On the other hand there are a lot of certainty about Kings David and Salomon. But the bible is not a serious source of historicity. Look for example the gospel of Marcos, it begins with Jesus being baptized in Jordan by John, he tells nothing about God being his father ... He is just an adopted son of God in that gospel

Edit your comment into the question body itself. The fundamental supposition that the bible is not a serious source of history is debatable, and indeed is hotly debated, but perhaps if you scope your question to answers that can make that assumption or a similar one, you may get an answer that you like. Do give some time to the [tour] when you can. Welcome to C.SE!

Thanks. I'll take your advise

Cain traveling to Iran is completely contrary to Scripture. Cain was not on the Ark; therefore, a) he died, and b) wherever he was buried is lost because it was destroyed by the Flood. Of course, there are many other things contrary to Scripture in Muslim beliefs, so it's not too surprising they would get this wrong too.

Thanks ! That was my point. Muslim people believe in another different story. Soooo you have to pick one story, what do you choose ??


Since some biblical characters, like Kings David and Salomon did exist, but others didn't ( I am assuming that Noah didn't,for instance, although some people think he really lived a lot of years ago)

Noah obviously existed. Practically every civilization that ever existed attests to this fact in their writings and oral traditions about the Great Flood, many of which are only partly preserved or are only partly translated correctly. However for example, the ancient Egyptians claim that all human beings are descended through eight individuals, namely, a person whose name Egyptologists transliterate as "Nu" (equivalent to "Noah" in modern English) and his three sons and their wives, who managed to be the sole survivors of a great flood aboard a ship constructed for that purpose. Approximate transliterations of the names of the company have been debated by scholars but more recent analogues in languages sharing common descent with ancient Egyptian including Arabic and Hebrew show the pronunciations of the names of all three sons and are lexically and semantically indistinguishable from the Biblical Ham, Shem and Japheth. The Egyptians acknowledged that they were descendants of Ham, one of the sons of Noah. The very existence of "Semites" (literally, "Shemites") today is also linguistic and historic proof of the existence of Shem, one of the three sons of Noah. Mitochondrial and Y DNA haplogroups also show that humanity is descended from three main branches stemming from an unexpected, recent bottleneck event relative to the ever-moving goalposts of Darwinian theory. "Scholars" pretending that a global Flood didn't happen base their reasoning in every case on circular premises.
I can't think of a Biblical persona who didn't actually exist (except for people in parables, which are typically true but anonymized or typified stories).

"I was wondering ... Did Cain really exist?"

Yes, Cain really existed, as did Abel, Adam and Eve.
The Scriptural record is the most correct of any history, and all bona fide historical records agree as to the factuality of Scriptural events. Subsequent paganization of each culture and mistranslation of lost languages has led to corruption of the accounts of the Great Flood, but the common denominator across every culture and civilization comports exactly with the Biblical record.
The Scriptures do not appear to say where or when Cain died or where or whether he was buried. Records might exist showing the remainder of his account, but until these are located and translated correctly, theories about his death and burial a are speculative at best.

But it sounds weird ... Everybody coming from Adam and Eve ... It's just it seems weird. We all began as monkeys, in what point do you suppose that the first humans did appear ?? And not only you know that, you also know their names ... It's kind of weird. Furthermore a lot of writings speaking about the same story does not guarantee that the story is true, it only proofs that such a story is popular. I'm writing this from a deep and profound respect to your beliefs, that somehow are also mine. But this is too weird

@Evariste Thankfully, what is true does not depend on what "sounds weird" to the natural man. We did not descend from monkeys or apes. That is the weird thought.
God created Adam and Eve after His own image and likeness.  It is not strange that we know their names. God taught them to read and write, and they did, and that is how we know about them. Imagine if the Scriptures didn't exist: Modern genetics point us to the reality that we are all indeed descended from first parents in the very recent past, which Darwinism never in a million years would have predicted, but the Bible did.

But it's a sorrow to me to deny what you say. Modern biology indeed tells that everybody currently living on this planet can be traced back to some common origins. They are called Adam and Eve, like in the Bible. But they are just a model, they didn't even lived in the same location or at the same time... You're wrong

@Evariste Evolutionists are wrong. Adaptation and natural selection are observable and true phenomena. However, "mutation" as a driver is pathetically ineffective at producing anything except sterility, miscarriage, death, cancer, and loss of fitness. Meiosis and genetic recombination are a million times more efficient at producing genomic variety--using already-functioning and fit genotypes--than mutation is at producing point variations, the vast majority of which are deleterious or nonfunctional.

@Evariste Claims that Y Adam and Mitochondrial Eve(s) did not coexist are ill-founded and incorrect. All that can possibly be said on the subject genetically is that, equipped only with a certain subset of evidence it "might not be conclusive" that they coexisted. That is not the same things as saying that they definitely didn't coexist. On the contrary, the more we learn, the more finely we are able to triangulate their existence through alternative means and to this day there is no evidence providing a contraindication to the reality that they lived at the same time.

Y "Adam" lived about 2500 BC. I've seen claims that place Mitochondrial Eve ~4000 BC, which would be Genesis 1 Eve, while the Y bottleneck is actually Noah. So, technically, they didn't coexist, but you also said "Eve(s)", plural, which is consistent with Noah and his sons' wives.

Studies of wild malaria demonstrated the ability to gain anti-malarial drug resistance, which required two coordinated mutations. This is arguably the "best" example of a gain-of-function mutation. It took decades, in an organism whose numbers and reproduction rate make complex lifeforms look like they're sterile and effectively extinct. The idea that humans and other apes could differentiate meaningfully in a mere few hundred thousand years is ludicrous. (Continued...)

(...Continued) What we actually see is that organisms can diversify extremely rapidly, but on the basis of information that already existed, and which is often lost in the process. Any small breeding population today is invariably less healthy and less sustainable than its ancestors even a few decades ago. All this goes to clearly show that diverse genetic information was present from the start, and isn't increasing, but decreasing. Now, it's true we have a common "origin", but that "origin" is a common Designer. Humans were never apes, much less monkeys.

@Evariste, it's true that practically every culture having a Flood story doesn't make it true. What it does strongly suggest, however, is a common origin... and since materialist timelines don't allow for the relevant cultures to overlap at the necessary times, that's strong evidence that those cultures actually dispersed from a common source closer to 2000 BC - 3000 BC. On top of that, the narrative is generally regarded as historical until recent times. This all makes perfect sense if Scripture is true, but presents a serious puzzle otherwise.

@Matthew Not just a puzzle, but a serious and consistent chorus of anomalies that threaten the assumptions upon which Scripture as history was dismissed.
